# JavaScript local storage issues

Tags: javascript

I am trying to post objects from a bootstrap modal to the local storage in JavaScript. The set of details gets posted to the local storage but the other form entries do not. Here is my code.

```
//function to add tasks to the loacal storage
function addTask() {
  myTasks.push(new TaskManager(id,taskName.value,assignedTo.value,dueDate.value,statusButton.value,description.value ));
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(myTasks));
}
```

Comment: Probably those "other form entries", whatever they are, are not enumerable. Check the output of `JSON.stringify`, this probably has nothing to do with local storage.

Comment: I am very new JavaScript. can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: I'd console.log anything you push to localStorage and determine if it's in proper JSON.stringify/parse format.

Comment: start with this `console.log(JSON.stringify(myTasks))` and check the browser development window to see what you are storing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your TaskManager object is not being created correctly. Check by sending the object that you are managing to create, as a parameter of the addTask() function.

Comment: Shall I share my full code?

Comment: Yes, it will help. If you can't debug your code and can share the code. Try putting it on JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/).